# iPad screenshots no longer accepted by iTunes Connect

Tags: ipad, app-store-connect

Have had no problems submitting screenshots to iTunes Connect until now.  I just cropped out the status bar using Preview of a .png screenshot taken on my iPad mini to get the required dimensions and dragged/dropped.  But I now get the "Incorrect Dimensions in one or more..." message.

Have tried using the simulator for different iPads to produce different dimensions.  The only one that produces a screenshot acceptable to iTunes Connect is the iPad Pro simulator (2048 x 2732).  But the results are inconsistent.  They mostly show smaller images with added vertical white space, but in the case of one landscape view, certain views were placed incorrectly (although the other iPad non-Pro simulators did not have this problem).
  iTunes Connect does say the 12.9" (pro) images may be used for other iPad sizes, but it looks like that simulator has problems.  Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain this

**They mostly show smaller images with added vertical white space, but in the case of one landscape view, certain views were placed incorrectly (although the other iPad non-Pro simulators did not have this problem).**

When you take screenshots on the simulator make sure that Window->Scale is set to 100%.

Apple has finally changed the iTunes connect screenshots system this year. You can now upload 5 screenshots for the highest res devices (iPhone 6Plus and iPad Pro) and they will be used for all the lower res devices as well. 
Before you would have to upload screenshots for all the other devices as well and it sucked. Now add support for 27 languages and I believe you would have to upload over 800 images, it was insane. Even Apple took the piss about this in one of their keynotes this year.

So you should take/use screenshots in iPhone 6 Plus resolution (2208×1242 or 1242×2208) and in iPad Pro resolution (2732×2048 or 2048×2732).

If you can take screenshots in the simulator than great, but my games run like crap there so I take them on my real iPhone 7/iPad Air 2 and scale them up. Not 100% ideal but I cannot really do anything else at the moment.

The same applies for videos, just upload them in 1920x1080 for the iPhone and you are good to go. For the iPad you would need to change the resolution of the video.

My games on the appStore do not have a video trailer for iPad because I could never convert the video correctly in iPad resolution for iTunes connect to accept the upload. However they still show you the iPhone video preview on iPads, so thats pretty awesome. I wonder if the same applies for screenshots, so if you do not upload iPad screenshots it will use the iPhone ones.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem was mostly caused by my not realizing that I was dragging and dropping into an area that would only accept 12.9" screenshots.  It looked just like the area into which I always copied screenshots, and I don't remember seeing "12.9" and "other sizes" shown below (was I possibly looking at an old iTunes Connect page from my cache?).  If you click on "other sizes", you will get an area into which you can drop 9.7 screenshots.

The result was that Apple accepted my build, and when it showed up in the store, none of the 12.9" simulator-generated screenshots that I referenced in my app description showed up.  Not sure why this happened, but apparently I now have to provide a new version which will now use 9.7 screenshots taken from my iPad.

I don't know why the iPad Pro (12.9) simulator messed up my landscape orientation (which I replaced with a portrait).  It may be my app, which creates layout constraints programmatically, but they appear to work with the other iPad simulators.